# How to get the user location using url path of facebook graph?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, laravel-5, facebook-graph-api-v2.2

Right now i can get the user's name,avatar,email of the user but when i try to use this for location https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/1234567890/location im getting this message

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Unknown path components: /location",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 2500
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

resource url for user location is `{id}/locations`.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/1234567890/locations
```

unfortunately , locations resource was deprecated in v2.0 or higher.accessing the above url will return

```
{
"error": {
  "message": "(#12) user locations API is deprecated for versions v2.0 and higher",
  "type": "OAuthException",
  "code": 12
         }
}
```

Comment: but is there any way to get the user's location? or i have to wait until my facebook app is done for review?

Comment: you can use older versions resource url like this `https://graph.facebook.com/1234567890/locations` . Omitting the version(version 1.0 will be used). But try to avoid using deprecated resources.